# Error While Writing into a Hive table from Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to insert data into a Hive External table from Spark Sql.
I am created the hive external table through the following command

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  tab1 ( col1 type,col2 type ,col3 type) CLUSTERED BY (col1,col2) SORTED BY (col1) INTO 8 BUCKETS STORED AS PARQUET
```

In my spark job , I have written the following code
Dataset df = session.read().option("header","true").csv(csvInput);

```
df.repartition(numBuckets, somecol)
                  .write()
                  .format("parquet")
                  .bucketBy(numBuckets,col1,col2)
                  .sortBy(col1)
                  .saveAsTable(hiveTableName);
```

Each time I am running this code I am getting the following exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table `tab1` already exists.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:393)
    at somepackage.Parquet_Read_WriteNew.writeToParquetHiveMetastore(Parquet_Read_WriteNew.java:100)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the `saveAsTable` API, which create the table into Hive. Since you have already created the hive table through command, the table `tab1` already exists. so when Spark API trying to create it, it throws error saying table already exists, `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table`tab1`already exists.`

Either drop the table and let spark API `saveAsTable` create the table itself.
Or use the API `insertInto` to insert into an existing hive table.

```
df.repartition(numBuckets, somecol)
                  .write()
                  .format("parquet")
                  .bucketBy(numBuckets,col1,col2)
                  .sortBy(col1)
                  .insertInto(hiveTableName);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be specifying a **save mode** while saving the data in hive.

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
              .format("parquet")
              .bucketBy(numBuckets,col1,col2)
              .sortBy(col1)
              .insertInto(hiveTableName);
```

Spark provides the following save modes:

**Save Mode**

`ErrorIfExists`: Throws an exception if the target already exists. If target doesn’t exist write the data out.

`Append`: If target already exists, append the data to it. If the data doesn’t exist write the data out.

`Overwrite`: If the target already exists, delete the target. Write the data out.

`Ignore`: If the target already exists, silently skip writing out. Otherwise write out the data.

Comment: insertInto might not be an option for me , as I have bucketing in my tables. Is there a way to circumvent that?